# Chapter 3 Hoffman Kunze Linear Algebra exercise 12

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p$, $m$, and $n$ be positive integers and $F$ a field. Let $V$ be the space of $m \times n$ matrices over $F$ and $W$ the space of $p \times n$ matrices over $F$. Let $B$ be a fixed $p \times m$ matrix and let $T$ be the linear transformation from $V$ into $W$ defined by $T(A)=BA$. Prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if $p=m$ and $B$ is an invertible $m \times m$ matrix.

I can prove that $T$ is invertible iff $p\leq m$ by using the non-singularity propriety of $T$, but I can't go further.

Comment: Type \$\times\$ to get $\times$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by invertible, you mean there exists a transformation $T^{-1}$ so that $TT^{-1}, T^{-1}T$ are both the identity. But then this means that $T$ gives an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$. In particular, $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension as vector spaces. So we must have $m=p$. Then $B$ is an $m \times m$ matrix and we see that the matrix corresponding to $T^{-1}$ must be the inverse of $B$. So $B$ is indeed invertible.

Comment: Isn't any matrix representing $T^{-1}$ an $(mn)\times(mn)$ matrix, instead of $m\times m$?

Comment: In general, a linear transformation of an $mn$-dimensional vector space can be represented (with a choice of basis) as an $mn \times mn$ matrix. However, in this case, we are given that $T$ is the linear map that takes $A \mapsto BA$. Then applying $B^{-1}$ to any element in the image of $T$, we see that $B^{-1}(BA)=A$, so that $T^{-1}$ is indeed given by multiplication by the matrix $B^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and now I understand what you meant by "corresponding to $T^{-1}$".  (I thought you were referring to the matrix representing $T^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm glad this clarifies things. Best wishes!

Answer (score 3):

Since $col_{j}(BA)=B(col_{j}(A))$,

$A\in Ker(T)\iff col_{j}(A)\in Nullspace(B)$ for $1\le j\le n$.

$\Rightarrow$
If $p=m$ and B is invertible, then T is invertible since $\dim V=\dim W$ and
$Ker(T)=\{0\}$ since $Nullspace(B)=\{0\}$.

$\Leftarrow$
If T is invertible, then $\dim V=\dim W$ so $p=m$, and $Ker(T)=\{0\}\implies Nullspace(B)=\{0\}\implies$ B is invertible.

Comment: What do you mean by $col_{j}$?

Comment: I'm using that notation for the jth column of the matrix involved.